# substring in postgresql with additional criteria based on the position of a character

Tags: postgresql

I am hitting a SQL query below and resulting as show below.
`SELECT column from Table LIMIT =1`

> GLOBE-WORLD-AIRPORT-Azerbaijan-country-SECRET-ABORT

Here I want to get the data `Azerbaijan-country` as my result. My logic should fetch the content after the third - and the second - from the last. So that I can get the required result. How to do this in PostgreSQL.

Comment: 1. `column` and `table` are both reserved keywords, so you'd need to double-quote those. 2. `LIMIT` accepts the parameter directly, without `=`. 3. Which PostgreSQL version are you working with? 4. What have you tried so far? Here's a chapter on [pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_substr()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#1.5.8.10.7.2.2.27.1.1.1) in PostgreSQL 15+: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AU37qp88)

```
select regexp_substr("column",'([^-]*-){3}(.*)(-[^-]*){2}', 1, 1, 'i', 2) 
from "Table"
limit 1;
```

| regexp_substr |
| --- |
| Azerbaijan-country |

You can read more on pattern matching in PostgreSQL [in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

1. `[^-]` means any character except a hyphen.
2. `([^-]*-)` means any amount of non-hyphens followed by a hyphen.
3. **`([^-]*-){3}`** means 3 repetitions of that. This is looking for your initial three hyphens and anything they separate.
4. **`(.*)`** is any amount of any character. This is what you want to catch
5. `(-[^-]*)` is a hyphen followed by any amount of non-hyphens.
6. **`(-[^-]*){2}`** looks for two of those after your target.
7. The parameters after the pattern `1, 1, 'i', 2` mean (in this order) that you want to

   - start counting from the **1**st character of your text value
   - get only **1** hit
   - search case-**i**nsensitively,
   - get the hit in the **2**nd parenthesised group - the `(.*)`.

---

In earlier versions all the way back to 8.1, you can use [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to wipe everything around your target: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cgzhb_Xf)

```sql
select regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace( "column"
                           ,'^([^-]*-){3}'
                           ,'')
           ,'(-[^-]*){2}$'
           ,'')
from "Table";
```

This uses `^` outside `[]` as beginning of line idicator and `$` as end of line indicator.

In 8.3+, if you prefer simpler patterns, you can `regexp_split_to_array()` and grab an array [slice](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/arrays.html#AEN6091) between element 4 and 2-back-from-last:

```sql
select array_to_string(w[4:array_upper(w,1)-2],'-')
from "Table",
regexp_split_to_array("column",'-')_(w);
```

Either way, make sure you don't stay behind [at least](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) version 12 for too long - that's the oldest supported version until November 14 2024.

Comment: I am getting this error. 
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function regexp_substr(text, unknown, integer, integer, unknown, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Looks like the solution you have found is working in the version greater than 15 or 15. But we have the version lesser than that. Any advise on this.

Comment: @JohnsonAnthony That's exactly why it's a [good idea to include what version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77915210/substring-in-postgresql-with-additional-criteria-based-on-the-position-of-a-char/77915396#comment137361130_77915210) you're working with. I've added a method using the same pattern syntax, but working on versions 9.4-14 as well.

Answer (score 0):

There Some doubts about used RDBMS.
I will offer a solution without using regexp.

Example 3. Tested  with PostgreSQL from  9.3 to 16

```
with recursive r as(
select id,words,1 rn
  ,case when strpos(words,'-')>0 then substring(words,strpos(words,'-')+1)
   else words
   end rest
  ,case when strpos(words,'-')>0 then substring(words,1,strpos(words,'-')-1)
   else words
   end w
from test
  union all
select id,words,rn+1 rn
  ,case when strpos(rest,'-')>0 then substring(rest,strpos(rest,'-')+1)
   else ''
   end rest
  ,case when strpos(rest,'-')>0 then substring(rest,1,strpos(rest,'-')-1)
   else rest
   end w
from r
where length(rest)>0
)
select id,words
  ,string_agg(w,'-' order by wn) newWords
from(
    select *
      ,rn wn
      ,count(*)over(partition by id ) cnt
    from r
   )t
where wn>3 and wn<=(cnt-2)
group by id,words
```

Example 1. Tested  with PostgreSQL from  14 to 16

```
select id,words
  ,string_agg(w,'-' order by rn) newWords
from(
    select *
      ,row_number()over(partition by id order by (select null)) rn
      ,count(*)over(partition by id order by (select null)) cnt
    from(select *,string_to_table(words,'-') w from test )t
  )t2
where rn>3 and rn<=(cnt-2)
group by id,words
```

Example 2. Tested  with PostgreSQL from  14 to 16
(using ordinality -  @Zegarek)

```
select id,words
  ,string_agg(w,'-' order by wn) newWords
from(
    select *
      ,ordinality wn
      ,count(*)over(partition by id order by (select null)) cnt
    from(select *
         from test 
         cross join string_to_table(words,'-') with ordinality as w
   )t
  )t2
where wn>3 and wn<=(cnt-2)
group by id,words
```

Output is

| id | words | newwords |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GLOBE-WORLD-AIRPORT-Azerbaijan-country-SECRET-ABORT | Azerbaijan-country |
| 2 | GLOBE-WORLD-AIRPORT-Azerbaijan-country-SECRET | Azerbaijan |

from test data

| id | words |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | GLOBE-WORLD-AIRPORT-Azerbaijan-country-SECRET-ABORT |
| 2 | GLOBE-WORLD-AIRPORT-Azerbaijan-country-SECRET |
| 3 | GLOBE-WORLD-AIRPORT-Azerbaijan-country |
| 4 | GLOBE-WORLD-AIRPORT-Azerbaijan |
| 5 | GLOBE-WORLD-AIRPORT |
| 6 | GLOBE-WORLD |

string_to_table actual from postgresql 14.

Comment: [`string_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html) improves the supported version range by just 1: the doubt you refer to is due to the fact `regexp_substring()` was added in PostgreSQL **15**. `string_to_table()` was added in **14**. `regexp_replace()` [added as a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77915396/5) reaches all the way back to **9.4**, so the regular expressions you're trying to sidestep actually predate your method.

Comment: Yes, only down to PostgreSQL 14.

Comment: I think you might also want to [`string_to_table(words,'-')with ordinality as stt(w,n)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) so that you can `order by n` in your window definition. Otherwise, you can skip it entirely and leave just `over(partition by id)` because ordering by nothing only adds text while achieving nothing.

Comment: Yes, this is better. I will update answer. Thank you.

Comment: I added a version with a recursive query. Works from 9.3

Comment: [Recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/queries-with.html) worked even in **8.4** but that still loses to regexp family of functions that [appeared in **8.1**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-string.html), if you're attempting to go as far back as possible. Still, commendable effort.

Comment: Zegarek, thank you for very useful comments. Perhaps the options you and I have suggested are more than enough.